# URL parsing with "?" does not work

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

[An answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214778/828) includes an URL with a *?*, which is not correctly parsed.
I think it should be.

Actually, I wanted to include the image that is autogenerated from the URL, to show a point of my answer, this did also not work.

Answer (score 5):

It is not the question mark that is at issue there. You need to properly quote your URL parameters; it is the backslash and braces that cause the query parameter to be ignored.

Rather than use:

```
https://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?\sum^{i%3D\infty}_{i%3D0}x_{i}}
```

use

```
https://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%5Csum%5E%7Bi%3D%5Cinfty%7D_%7Bi%3D0%7Dx_%7Bi%7D%7D
```

The backslash, caret and braces are all quoted now, not just the `=` equals signs.

This is recognised as a proper URL:  https://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%5Csum%5E%7Bi%3D%5Cinfty%7D_%7Bi%3D0%7Dx_%7Bi%7D%7D

and is usable as an image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wasn't aware of this. Could the "proper" quoting be implemented in the URL parser?

Comment: @Habi: no, because then any sentence ending in a URL and a question mark would pull in the rest of the post. That's what proper URL quoting is *for*, so that URLs can be properly recognised and handled.

Comment: That makes sense. This makes my orginal answer less usable then, since a simple copy-paste link for embedding in a forum was asked for :)

Comment: @Habi: you need to include a [online URL encoding step](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=online+url+encode) in that case.